Configure GPT to send 'ngrok-skip-browser-warning' request header in ngrok
I a making a GPT using ngrok, I try to send OAuth2 tokens using gpt actions. This is a part of my schema in json:
 "/event_types/event_type": {
  "get": {
    "description": "Obtiene un tipo de evento existente",
    "operationId": "GetTipoEvento",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "event",
        "in": "query",
        "description": "Tipo de evento a consultar",
        "required": true,
        "schema": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "ngrok-skip-browser-warning",
        "in": "header",
        "description": "Encabezado para saltar la advertencia del navegador de ngrok",
        "required": true,
        "schema": {
          "type": "string",
          "default": "true"
        }
      }
    ],
    "deprecated": false
  }

I get this error

when I execute an action I get this:

{"response_data": "\n<html class="h-full" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">\n  \n    <link rel="preload" href="https://cdn.ngrok.com/static/fonts/euclid-square/EuclidSquare-Regular-WebS.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous" />\n    <link rel="preload" href="https://cdn.ngrok.com/static/fonts/euclid-square/EuclidSquare-RegularItalic-WebS.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous" />\n    <link rel="preload" href="https://cdn.ngrok.com/static/fonts/euclid-square/EuclidSquare-Medium-WebS.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous" />\n    <link rel="preload" href="https://cdn.ngrok.com/static/fonts/euclid-square/EuclidSquare-Semibold-WebS.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous" />\n    <link rel="preload" href="https://cdn.ngrok.com/static/fonts/euclid-square/EuclidSquare-MediumItalic-WebS.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous" />\n    <link rel="preload" href="https://cdn.ngrok.com/static/fonts/ibm-plex-mono/IBMPlexMono-Text.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous" />\n    <link rel="preload" href="https://cdn.ngrok.com/static/fonts/ibm-plex-mono/IBMPlexMono-TextItalic.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous" />\n    <link rel="preload" href="https://cdn.ngrok.com/static/fonts/ibm-plex-mono/IBMPlexMono-SemiBold.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous" />\n    <link rel="preload" href="https://cdn.ngrok.com/static/fonts/ibm-plex-mono/IBMPlexMono-SemiBoldItalic.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous" />\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta name="author" content="ngrok">\n    <meta name="description" content="ngrok is the fastest way to put anything on the internet with a single command.">\n    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">\n    <link id="style" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.ngrok.com/static/css/error.css">\n    You are about to visit cc55-200-94-17-166.ngrok-free.app, served by 200.94.17.166. This website is served for free through ngrok.com. You should only visit this website if you trust whoever sent the link to you. (ERR_NGROK_6024)\n    <script id="script" src="https://cdn.ngrok.com/static/js/error.js" type="text/javascript">\n  \n  <body class="h-full" id="ngrok">\n    <div id="root" data-payload="eyJjZG5CYXNlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9jZG4ubmdyb2suY29tLyIsImNvZGUiOiI2MDI0IiwiaG9zdHBvcnQiOiJjYzU1LTIwMC05NC0xNy0xNjYubmdyb2stZnJlZS5hcHAiLCJtZXNzYWdlIjoiWW91IGFyZSBhYm91dCB0byB2aXNpdCBjYzU1LTIwMC05NC0xNy0xNjYubmdyb2stZnJlZS5hcHAsIHNlcnZlZCBieSAyMDAuOTQuMTcuMTY2LiBUaGlzIHdlYnNpdGUgaXMgc2VydmVkIGZvciBmcmVlIHRocm91Z2ggbmdyb2suY29tLiBZb3Ugc2hvdWxkIG9ubHkgdmlzaXQgdGhpcyB3ZWJzaXRlIGlmIHlvdSB0cnVzdCB3aG9ldmVyIHNlbnQgdGhlIGxpbmsgdG8geW91LiIsInNlcnZpbmdJUCI6IjIwMC45NC4xNy4xNjYiLCJ0aXRsZSI6Ik9LIn0=">\n  \n\n",
"status_code": 200,
"action_id": "g-dfcebb8885c9ed82ca6f3341fd3a45ea613cbeff"
}


